# selective removal from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list whose elements consist of a date object followed by several integers:

```
lis1 = {{desiredDate, 1, 2}, {desiredDate, 3, 4}, {desiredDate, 5, 6}, {desiredDate, 7, 8}};
```

I have a similarly structured list with dates that may extend from one to four days before desiredDate:

```
lis2 = {{undesiredDate, 1, 2},{undesiredDate, 5, 6}}
```

I would like to remove from lis1 all elements where the non-date elements of lis2 match, to give:

```
res = {desiredDate, 3, 4},{desiredDate, 7, 8}}
```

Thanks for ideas on how to do this.

Comment: `Select[lis1, ! MemberQ[Rest /@ lis2, Rest[#]] &]`

Answer (score 3):

```
DeleteCases[lis1, Alternatives @@ ({_, ##2} & @@@ lis2)]
```

> ```
> {{desiredDate, 3, 4}, {desiredDate, 7, 8}}
> ```

Comment: I would like to learn more about ## usage. Can you please suggest a resource?

Comment: @Syed, see [SlotSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) in the docs. (Or highlight `##` in the input notebook and hit F1).

Answer (score 2):

signatures to be removed if found matching `Rest@lis1`:

```
signature = Rest /@ lis2
```

> {{1, 2}, {5, 6}}

Write a function that tests membership and deletes matching signatures:

```
f[k_List, s_List] := If[MemberQ[s, Rest@k ], Nothing, k]
```

Execute:

```
f[#, signature] & /@ lis1
```

> {{desiredDate, 3, 4}, {desiredDate, 7, 8}}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove items from lis1 that have a date  0 to 4 days later than any date in lis2.

Toward this aim, you could use `DayCount`. Then:

```
((0 <= # <= 4) & /@ (DayCount[lis2, #])) &
```

is a function that returns a list of True/False if the argument is 0 to 4 days before the entries in lis2. `Or` and negation will give True if the argument is NOT in any of these intervals:

```
! Or @@ ((0 <= # <= 4) & /@ (DayCount[lis2, #])) &
```

Then we can use `Select`to get the entries from lis1 we want.
Here is an example:

```
d1 = DateObject[{2010, 4, 2}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.`];
d2 = DateObject[{2013, 11, 12}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.`];
d3 = DateObject[{2017, 2, 3}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.`];
n1 = DateObject[{2010, 4, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.`];
n2 = DateObject[{2013, 11, 12}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.`];
lis1 = {d1,  d2, d3};
lis2 = {n1, n2};

Select[lis1, ! Or @@ ((0 <= # <= 4) & /@ (DayCount[lis2, #])) &]
```

[image]